# How does Python distinguish if a parameter is default?

Tags: python-3.x, parameters

```
a = iter([1])
next(a)
next(a)
```

raises StopIteration

---

```
a = iter([1])
next(a)
next(a, None)
```

there is no StopIteration

---

however the defination of `next`is

`def next(iterator, default=None):`

How does Python distinguish if the parameter is default or user-given?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The builtin function `next` doesn't use `None` as its default. In fact, as you can see in the C source code (for cpython, the official Python interpreter), [its argument handling is very low level](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/52b940803860e37bcc3f6096b2d24e7c20a0e807/Python/bltinmodule.c#L1372). The pure Python equivalent would be using `*args` in the function definition and and manually checking that you got either one or two arguments. Here's what that might look like:

```
def next(*args):
    assert(1 <= len(args) <= 2)
    try:
        return args[0].__next__()
    except StopIteration:
        if len(args) > 1:
            return args[1]
        else:
            raise
```

A better way to replicate similar behavior in Python is to use a default value that is not possible for outside code to accidentally supply. Here's one good way to do it:

```
_sentinel = object() # a unique object that no user should ever pass to us

def next(iterator, default=_sentinel):
    try:
        return iterator.__next__()
    except StopIteration:
        if default is not _sentinel:
            return default
        else:
            raise
```